# Ubuntu 16.04 sudo apt-get update stuck at "Starting at x x x x x "

Tags: 16.04, apt, upgrade, updates

```
Hit:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gedit-bc-dev-plugins/releases/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease              
Hit:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/test/ubuntu xenial InRelease 
Hit:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/atom/ubuntu xenial InRelease        
Hit:5 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease         
Hit:6 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease
Hit:7 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease
Hit:8 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Starting at Fri Aug 18 17:43:24 2017
```

I could never run apt-get update completely. The process get stuck at Starting at ..... as given above. It's never ending. I once let it run for almost a day. Only thing I can do is to force stop the process using Ctrl+z. What should I do?

Comment: Please remove the source `https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu xenial InRelease` from the package sources list in your Software Center and try again.

Comment: @dessert thanks for your response. Unfortunately, that didn't work. It's still stuck at Starting at.

Comment: Please provide the output of `sudo apt update`now after disabling this source.

Comment: I suspect the last source before the “Starting at” line to be the problem, fyi…

Comment: `Hit:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gedit-bc-dev-plugins/releases/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:2 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease          
Hit:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease
Hit:4 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease       
Hit:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/test/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:6 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease     
Hit:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/atom/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Starting at Fri Aug 18 20:04:08 2017`  @dessert The output is as above

Comment: Does `sudo apt update` give the same result?

Comment: Yes ,  I am getting the same  @dessert

Comment: @dessert the problem was solved after I have updated the os. There was an update available in software center, after doing which the issue was solved. Thanks for your response though :-)